# How to create list of names of customers who have exceed the number of transactions in day and transaction limit

Tags: mysql, sql

table 1

```
'name'              'amount'           'day'
---------------------------------------------
hemanth        10000      2019-06-21
hemanth        1000       2019-06-21
hemanth        5000       2019-06-21
hemanth        10000      2019-07-21    
kumar          100        2019-06-21
kumar          5000       2019-06-21
kumar          1000      2019-07-21
kiranmai       10000     2019-06-21
kiranmai       500      2019-07-21
kiranmai       10000     2019-06-21
```

table 2 contains transcation limit per day & transcation amount limit

```
tranlimperday                transamontlim
--------------------------------------------
3                      10000
```

I am already convert the Date column into Day and month wise but after that we need find the count of transactions in day  and sum of amount for thta we need to capmare the month column with  month(date) but Im unable to find the query

expect oputput

```
Name
---------
Hemanth
kiranmai
```

Comment: Can you add the query you are trying with so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two separate queries and `union`:

```
select name
from (select name, day,
             sum(amount) as total_amount, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      group by name, day
     ) nd join
     table2 t2
     on t1.cnt >= t2.tranlimperday
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select name
from (select name, year(day) as yyyy, month(day) as mm,
             sum(amount) as total_amount, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      group by name, year(day), month(day)
     ) nym join
     table2 t2
     on t1.total_amount >= t2.transamontlim;
```

In MySQL 8+, you could also use window functions:

```
select distinct name
from (select name, day,
             sum(amount) as daily_total_amount, count(*) as daily_cnt,
             sum(sum(amount)) over (partition by name, year(day), month(day)) as monthly_total_amount,                  
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by name, year(day), month(day)) as monthly_cnt 
      from table1
      group by name, day
     ) nd join
     table2 t2
     on t1.daily_cnt >= t2.tranlimperday or
        t1.monthly_total_amount >= t2.transamontlim;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the aggregated results with either crossed daily transaction limit or crossed limit of daily translation amount limit. You can try this below option as well-

```
SELECT name,Day,
COUNT(1) num_tran,
SUM(amount) tran_amt 
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2 
GROUP BY name,Day,YEAR(day),MONTH(Day),DAY(Day)
HAVING COUNT(1) >= MAX(Table2.tranlimperday) -- Considering Single row in the table2
OR SUM(amount)  > MAX(Table2.transamontlim) -- Considering Single row in the table2
```